# Get value of HTTPClient in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

**data-sharing.service.ts**

```
public httpGetAll(owner: any) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/${owner}`, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      catchError(e => {
        throw new Error(e);
      })
    );
  }


public httpGetAllBy(id: number, byId:string, owner: any) {
    return this.httpGetAll(owner).subscribe(data => {
      Object.keys(data).map(function(key) {
        return data[key].filter(x => x[byId] === id);
      });
    })
```

**station.service.ts**

```
getStationsByOrg(id) {
    return this.dataSharing.httpGetAllBy(id, 'orgId', 'station');
  }
```

**managestation.component.ts**

```
getStationsByOrg(id) {
    this.sta = this.staService.getStationsByOrg(id);
  }
```

**managestation.component.html**

```
<ion-content class="body">
  <ion-button expand="block" (click)="onAddStation()">Add Station
    <ion-icon name='add' slot="end"></ion-icon>
  </ion-button>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let s of sta">
      <ion-label>{{ s.name }}</ion-label>
      <ion-label>{{ s.orgId }}</ion-label>
      <ion-icon name='create' slot="end" (click)="onEditStation(s.id)"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon name='trash' slot="end" (click)="onDeleteStation(s.id)"></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**Error**

> ERROR Error: "[object Object]"
>       Angular 11 core.js:4002

How can I get the values of *httpGetAllBy* in *managestation.component.ts* and assign it to this.sta. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your files as below

**data-sharing.service.ts**

```
public httpGetAllBy(id: number, byId:string, owner: any) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     this.httpGetAll(owner)
      .subscribe(data => {
        let filterdData = Object.keys(data).map(function(key) {
         return data[key].filter(x => x[byId] === id);
        });
        resolve(filterdData);
      })
    });
}
```

**managestation.component.ts**

```
getStationsByOrg(id) {
    this.staService.getStationsByOrg(id)
    .then((allData) => {
       this.sta = allData;
    })

  }
```

Comment: I have the following
getStationsByOrg()
getUsersByOrg()
getUsersByStation()
getTanksByStation()
getPumpsByStation()
getPumpsByTank()

so i want to make httpGetAllBy() have the filter function so i dont have to repeat it in all the function above

Comment: Modified answer using Promise way. Please check again.

Comment: ERROR in src/app/members/managestation/managestation.component.ts(65,10): error TS2739: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Station': id, name, orgId, status

it working using console.log(allData);
but get the error above in this.sta = allData;

Answer (score 0):

You should return an Observable in your service and map it through pipe().

```
public httpGetAllBy(id: number, byId:string, owner: any) {
    return this.httpGetAll(owner).pipe(
        map( (data => {
            Object.keys(data).map(function(key) {
                return data[key].filter(x => x[byId] === id);
            });
        }))
    );
}
```

Then you can subscribe to in your component.

Comment: ERROR in src/app/_services/data-sharing.service.ts(177,9): error TS2552: Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'?

Comment: No, you should import it from RxJS

Answer (score 0):

You are returning subscription, but not data. Options:

- 2) return observable itself:

  ```
  public httpGetAllBy(id: number, byId:string, owner: any) {
      return this.httpGetAll(owner);
  }
  getStationsByOrg(id) {
      return this.dataSharing.httpGetAllBy(id, 'orgId', 'station').subscribe(data=>{
        const var = Object.keys(data).map(function(key) {
          return data[key].filter(x => x[byId] === id);
        });
  //your logic in station.service.ts
  };
    }
  ```

  2) use async/await to get data:

  ```
  public async httpGetAllBy(id: number, byId:string, owner: any) {
      return await this.httpGetAll(owner).toPromise().then(data => {
        return Object.keys(data).map(function(key) {
          return data[key].filter(x => x[byId] === id);
        });
      })
  getStationsByOrg(id) {
      return this.dataSharing.httpGetAllBy(id, 'orgId', 'station').then(data=>{
  //your logic in station.service.ts
  };
  ```