# error TS2739: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

**managestation.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Station } from 'src/app/_models/station';
import { StationService } from 'src/app/_services/station.service';
import { AddStaModalComponent } from 'src/app/modal/station/add-sta-modal/add-sta-modal.component';
import { EditStaModalComponent } from 'src/app/modal/station/edit-sta-modal/edit-sta-modal.component';
import { DataSharingService } from 'src/app/_services/data-sharing.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-managestation',
  templateUrl: './managestation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./managestation.component.scss'],
})
export class ManagestationComponent implements OnInit {
  sta: Station;
  mySubscription: any;

  constructor(
    private dataSharing: DataSharingService,
    private staService: StationService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {}
  getStationsByOrg(id) {
      this.staService.getStationsByOrg(id)
      .then((allData) => {
        console.log(allData);
         this.sta = allData;
      });
    }
}
```

**managestation.component.html**

```
<ion-content class="body">
  <ion-button expand="block" (click)="onAddStation()">Add Station
    <ion-icon name='add' slot="end"></ion-icon>
  </ion-button>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let s of sta">
      <ion-label>{{ s.name }}</ion-label>
      <ion-label>{{ s.orgId }}</ion-label>
      <ion-icon name='create' slot="end" (click)="onEditStation(s.id)"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon name='trash' slot="end" (click)="onDeleteStation(s.id)"></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**station.ts**

```
import { StationStatus } from './station-status.enum';

export class Station {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    orgId: number;
    address?: string;
    status: StationStatus;

    constructor(id?: number, name?: string, orgId?: number, address?: string, status?: StationStatus) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.orgId = orgId;
        this.address = address;
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

**Terminal Error**

> ERROR in src/app/members/managestation/managestation.component.ts(66,10): error TS2739: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Station': id, name, orgId, status

**Console Output**

```
 Array [ (4) […] ]
managestation.component.ts:65:16

(1) […]
​
0: (4) […]
​​
0: Object { id: 5, orgId: 2, name: "BitCo Gas Jos North", … }
​​
1: Object { id: 6, orgId: 2, name: "BitCo Gas Awolowo Road ", … }
​​
2: Object { id: 7, orgId: 2, name: "BitCo Gas Kano Central", … }
​​
3: Object { id: 8, orgId: 2, name: "BitCo Gas Efik", … }
​​
length: 4
​​
<prototype>: Array []
​
length: 1
​
<prototype>: Array []
```

Am getting the result in console.log but i can't use it in my html component file

**Result**

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": 9,
      "orgId": 3,
      "name": "Conap Corp Ikeja",
      "address": "23, Ogunlowo Street, Obafemi Awolowway. Ikeja, Lagos",
      "status": "active"
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "orgId": 3,
      "name": "Conap Corp Ota",
      "address": "23, Ogunlowo Street, Obafemi Awolowway. Ikeja, Lagos",
      "status": "active"
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "orgId": 3,
      "name": "Conap Corp Agbara",
      "address": "23, Ogunlowo Street, Obafemi Awolowway. Ikeja, Lagos",
      "status": "active"
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "orgId": 3,
      "name": "Conap Corp Agbado",
      "address": "23, Ogunlowo Street, Obafemi Awolowway. Ikeja, Lagos",
      "status": "active"
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: Initial glance, if youre getting an array of stations back, this property: sta: Station; should be sta: Station[];

Comment: have try using `sta: Station[];` it still not working

Answer (score 2):

you also have another error, looking at your code:

```
export class Station {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    orgId: number;
    address?: string;
    status: StationStatus;

    constructor(id?: number, name?: string, orgId?: number, address?: string, status?: StationStatus) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.orgId = orgId;
        this.address = address;
        this.status = status;
    }
```

look at the attributes and please, note that. The problem is that if you look at the declaration, you are saying that most of those attributes can't be null, but if you look at the constructor, you are saying the opposite, which one is correct?

Comment: that can be a reason why the object is not identified, you have to match attribute name and type

Answer (score 1):

You receive an empty object `{}` from the API call and the type of data you **might** set for the API call is `Station`. Also, the `sta` type is `Station`:  `sta: Station;`. You cannot set an empty object to `sta`.

**Update:**

Looks like you are `allData` is an observable.

Comment: No, data return wasn't empty, have updated the question

Comment: am getting an array as result

Comment: `getStationsByOrg(id) {
    return this.dataSharing.httpGetAllBy(id, 'orgId', 'station')
    };`

Comment: Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59323612/get-value-of-httpclient-in-angular/59323977#59323977

Comment: @dominion is it possible to create a stackblitz?

Comment: thanks Maihan Nijat it working now
and i couldnt create an angular 8 project or stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

I added `allData[0]` and it working now

```
  getStationsByOrg(id) {
      this.staService.getStationsByOrg(id)
      .then((allData) => {
        console.log(allData);
        this.sta = allData[0];
      });
    }
```